# network distance from subjects to park within buffer

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have multiple subjects with buffers of 0.5 miles and parks in the city. I want to calculate a network distance between subjects and parks from each subjects with its buffer area. In some buffers there are 3 or more parks, so I want to know the distance of all the parks within the buffer. Is there any tool in ArcGIS 10 or higher and or already build model that I can use? 
In figure below, circles are 0.5 miles buffer of a subject (blue dots), red lines are the street, and colored polygons are the parks. I want to know the distances of each park within the polygon from the subjects (dots). I have more than 100 subjects and their buffer. Any Idea to do easily?
[image]

Comment: Similar task, might be useful. https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/06/30/park-analysis-and-design/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you're trying to find the distance from your subjects (Origins) to the parks (Destinations).  If you have access to the Network Analyst extension, you can do this relatively easily using the OD Cost Matrix tool.

To do it you would also need to convert your park polygons to a point layer (use the "Polygon to Point" tool).  Once you have that shapefile made, you would have to add the Subjects to your OD Cost Matrix Layer as Origins, add the Park_Points shapefile as the Destinations, and finally use your road network for the Network Layer (assuming you have a proper Network Dataset - http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//00470000005t000000).  Once you solve, you'll have a table with all of the combinations of Subjects (origins), Parks (destinations) and the distances between them.

Once all that was done, you could use Microsoft Access to filter the data by distance (effectively sorting by distances that are <0.5miles).  Also, you could assign an attribute to the parks using Select by Location <0.5 miles; then use the Join tool to indicate which parks have which Subjects within the buffer distance and query the database to narrow down your final product.

Kind of a convoluted explanation, but it should lead you in the right direction.